# How can I get limited number of rows from mysql using flask SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am unable to fetch a limited amount of rows. I always get an error whenever I attempt it.

Please note that i'm also trying to paginate the limited number of rows that are fetched.

The program works fine without using the limit. Its able to fetch randomly and paginate but gives an error when I try using .limit()

```
def question(page=1):
    # questions = Question.query.paginate(page, per_page=1)
    quess = Question.query.order_by(func.rand())
    quest = quess.limit(2)
    questions = quest.paginate(page, per_page=1)
```

This is the error I keep getting...

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError

InvalidRequestError: Query.order_by() being called on a Query which already has LIMIT or OFFSET applied. To modify the row-limited results of a  Query, call from_self() first.  Otherwise, call order_by() before limit() or offset() are applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `order_by()` after `limit()` in the same query. SQLAlchemy doesn't allow you to do that.
Try to use `from_self()` before calling `paginate()`.

```
Question.query.order_by(func.rand())
   .limit(2).from_self()
   .paginate(page, per_page=1)
```